# Javascript % Discount of Subtotal then add delivery cost,

Tags: javascript

I 20% off the Subtotal but then I need to add the delivery cost £4 if greater than 6 items in the bag. I looked at some examples on here and I tried to.

```
if (promoCode == '20off' || promoCode == '20OFF') {
    //If promoPrice has no value, set it as 20 for the 20OFF promocode
    if (!promoPrice) {
      promoPrice = promoPrice * 0.80;
    } else if (promoCode) {
      promoPrice = promoPrice * 1;
    }
  } else if (promoCode != '') {
    alert("Invalid Promo Code");
    promoPrice = 0;
  }
```

/* The example above won't work and nothing happens. the below is the example of the code I'm using that works but discounts only 0.80  */

```
$('.promo-code-cta').click(function() {

  promoCode = $('#promo-code').val();

  if (promoCode == '20off' || promoCode == '20OFF') {
    //If promoPrice has no value, set it as 20 for the 20OFF promocode
    if (!promoPrice) {
      promoPrice = 0.80;
    } else if (promoCode) {
      promoPrice = promoPrice * 1;
    }
  } else if (promoCode != '') {
    alert("Invalid Promo Code");
    promoPrice = 0;
  }
  //If there is a promoPrice that has been set (it means there is a valid promoCode input) show promo
  if (promoPrice) {
    $('.summary-promo').removeClass('hide');
    $('.promo-value').text(promoPrice.toFixed(2));
    recalculateCart(true);
  }
});

/* Recalculate cart */
function recalculateCart(onlyTotal) {
  var subtotal = 0;

  /* Sum up row totals */
  $('.basket-product').each(function() {
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.subtotal').text());
  });

  /* Calculate totals */
  var total = subtotal;

  //If there is a valid promoCode, and subtotal < 10 subtract from total
  var promoPrice = parseFloat($('.promo-value').text());
  if (promoPrice) {
    if (subtotal >= 10) {
      total -= promoPrice;
    } else {
      alert('Order must be more than £13 for Promo code to apply.');`enter code here`
      $('.summary-promo').addClass('hide');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry - what is promoPrice? What sort of value might it have?

Comment: let's say the price is £4.50 (450)

Comment: I just noticed the typo 

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it this way. It's not entirely clear what you are looking for. This will handle the cases you have enumerated above.

```js
// setup - putting some values in the variables
var promoPrice = "20";
const promoCode = "20OFF";

if (promoCode.toLowerCase() == "20off") {
    if (promoPrice > 0) {
        promoPrice *= 0.8;
        alert(`Discounting promoPrice to ${promoPrice}`);
    } else {
        promoPrice = 0.8;
        alert("no promoPrice. Setting to 0.8");
    }
} else if (promoCode != "") {
    promoPrice = 0;
    alert(`Invalid Promo Code. Setting promoPrice to 0.`);
} else {
    alert(`No Promo Code. Leaving promoPrice untouched at ${promoPrice}`);
}
```